# Best practices to implement SAML in REST services

Tags: java, apache, rest, cxf

We were looking to use Apache CXF framework to implement REST services. We would like to provide federated access to the rest services via SAML. The identify provider will a rest service (back ended by a DB) that would accept a user/pass and return a SAML assertion.

What would be the best practice in achieving this?

Answer (score 3):

Best practice is to conform to the SAML v2 Web Profile. But the problem there is that the Web Profile relies on sessions, typically managed by cookies. Sessions are a stateful artifact that are contrary to REST.

So, rather than using SAML, perhaps you should consider something like OAuth 2, which is a bit friendlier to HTTP and REST, since it can (by design) use the actual HTTP headers as part of its transaction and not rely on sessions.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to be a little loose in your definition of "RESTful", you may want to look at this:

http://cxf.apache.org/fediz.html

This is CXF's implementation of the SAML standard.

Or, follow the directions here to do it with CXF without the Fediz plugin:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/CXF20DOC/SAML+Web+SSO